# Number of rotations required to make string

Tags: java

This is my code to count the number of rotations.
But IDK, What is the problem with it.
Can anyone explain and help me out.

> Test Case: Input: david vidda
>
> Output: 2

I tried to have brute force approach but, that wasn't working even.
Can anyone point out my mistake??

```
import java.util.*;

class solution{
    public static int arrayLeftRotation(StringBuilder str1, StringBuilder str2) 
    {
     int i;
     int count =0;
     for (i = 0; i < str1.length(); i++){
        if(str1.equals(str2))
        { 
            count++; 
            str1 = leftRotatebyOne(str1); 
            System.out.println(str1);
        }
        else return count;
     }

        return count;
    }

    static StringBuilder leftRotatebyOne(StringBuilder str) 
    {
        int i;
        char temp = str.charAt(0);
        for (i = 0; i < str.length()-1; i++)
            str.setCharAt(str.indexOf(str.charAt(i)+""),str.charAt(i+1));
        str.setCharAt(i,temp);
        return str;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String strr1= in.nextLine();
        StringBuilder str1  = new StringBuilder(strr1);
        String strr2 = in.nextLine();
        StringBuilder str2  = new StringBuilder(strr2);
        System.out.print(arrayLeftRotation(str1, str2));
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't verify the algorithm but the statement `if(str1!=str2)` within `arrayLeftRotation` is certainly wrong: use `equals()` to compare objects

Comment: @RobertKock Hey, Thanks for replying. But that doesn't work even I tried that also! Please Help! Thanks!

Comment: Please edit with the corrected code using the equals method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method `leftRotateByOne` appears more complicated than necessary.
Try this:

```
public class Solution
{
  public static int arrayLeftRotation(String str1,
                                      String str2)
  {
    int nr_rotate;
    int counter;
    nr_rotate = 0;
    for (counter = 0; counter < str1.length(); counter++)
    {
      if (str1.equals(str2))
        return (nr_rotate);
      else
      {
        str1 = leftRotateByOne(str1);
        nr_rotate++;
        System.out.println(str1);
      }
    }

    // No possible solution
    return (-1);

  } // arrayLeftRotation

  public static String leftRotateByOne(String str)
  {
    return (str.substring(1) + str.charAt(0));
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String str1 = "david";
    String str2 = "vidda";
    System.out.print(arrayLeftRotation(str1, str2));
  }

} // class Solution
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks For your help! Worked!

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to append the input string to itself, then call `String#indexOf`. It will give you the index at which the doubled string contains the expected string, which is what you're looking for.

Example:

```
public static int numberOfRotations(String input, String expected) {
    final String doubledInput = input + input;
    return doubledInput.indexOf(expected);
}
```

---

If you **really** want to implement it yourself, you need to simplify your code to minimize the possibility of making mistakes.

```
public static String rotate(String input) {
    return input.substring(1) + input.charAt(0);
}

public static int numberOfRotations(String input, String expected) {
    // handle edge cases (null, empty, etc.) here
    String rotatedInput = input;
    int count = 0;
    while (!rotatedInput.equals(expected) && count < input.length()) {
        rotatedInput = rotate(rotatedInput);
        count++;
    }
    return count == input.length() ? -1 : count;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution for `arrayLeftRotation`,

```
public static int arrayLeftRotation(String str1, String str2) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(str1);
    for (int i = 0; i < str1.length(); i++) {
        builder.append(str1.charAt(i)).delete(0, 1);
        if (str2.equals(builder.toString())) {
            return i + 1;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Note: this will return `-1` if no matches found.

Comment: Can you explain me the logic behind the line:
builder.append(str1.charAt(i)).delete(0, 1);

Comment: @Shailesh200  builder contains string str1, first, char at position 'i' of str1 appends to end of builder then removes first character of builder until match is found

Answer (score 1):

*I am just trying to point out where your error lies and fix it.*

Your **error** lies here in your `leftRotatebyOne`:

```
for (i = 0; i < str.length()-1; i++) 
   str.setCharAt(str.indexOf(str.charAt(i)+""),str.charAt(i+1)); // your error while shifting to the left;
```

What you are trying to do is *shifting one position to the left*, and you should just do it as:

```
for (i = 0; i < str.length()-1; i++) 
   str.setCharAt(i,str.charAt(i+1));
```

And then your method will work.

But I have to say **Alex M** has provided a cleaner solution to your problem. Perhaps you should have a try.

Your solution then can be (after the fix):

```
public class RotationCount {
    public static int arrayLeftRotation(StringBuilder str1, StringBuilder str2) {
        int i;
        int count = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < str1.length(); i++) {
            if (!str1.toString().equals(str2.toString())) {
                count++;
                str1 = leftRotatebyOne(str1);
            } else return count;
        }
        return count;
    }

    static StringBuilder leftRotatebyOne(StringBuilder str) {
        int i;
        char temp = str.charAt(0);
        for (i = 0; i < str.length() - 1; i++) {
            str.setCharAt(i, str.charAt(i + 1));
        }
        str.setCharAt(i, temp);
        return str;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringBuilder str1 = new StringBuilder("david");
        StringBuilder str2 = new StringBuilder("vidda");
        System.out.print(arrayLeftRotation(str1, str2));
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks, Bro! Nice Solution though! Really appreciated!